# How to give default value if parameter is not set

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a search with an input field, like a filter. But if I'd fill just one field eg. language not working
code like this

```
  $counter = "%".{$_GET["count"]}."%";
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from CountryLanguage WHERE code LIKE ? AND counter LIKE ? AND language LIKE ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('sis', $code, $counter, $language);

  $code = 'DEU';
  $language = 'Bavarian';
```

if my `$language` will empty string, how to throw this error?

Comment: Hi! Maybe check you input data before binding?) if else, try catch?
P.S. If you want are default value, alter your fields in database, and add default values.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was my bad. That when I changed my variable toString; And instead to 's' I wrote 'i'. So this question is done